# write to a const reference of ostream

Tags: c++, reference, constants, cout

I am reading C++ primer. I encountered the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class PrintString {
public:
    PrintString(ostream &o = cout, char c = ' '): os(o), sep(c) {}
    void operator() (const string &s) const { os << s << sep; }
private:
    ostream &os;
    char sep;
};


int main() {
    const PrintString printer;

    printer("ABC");

    return 0;
}
```

This code works, but I don't know why. Below is what I think, it would be great if anyone could help to point out where I am wrong...

Here, 'printer' is a const PrintString object, so its data members are const, so 'printer.os' is a const reference to cout. Therefore, we should not be able to write to 'printer.os' since writing to cout changes it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your confusion with `const`-ness is better explained with a pointer rather than a reference.

Say you have:

```
struct A {int data;};

struct B
{
   B(A* ptr) : aPtr(ptr) {}
   A* aPtr;
};    

int main()
{
   A a1;
   A a2;
   const B b(&a1);
   // This makes b a const object.
   // This makes b.aPtr a const pointer. That means, you cannot change where it points to
   // but you can still change the value of what it points to.
   b.aPtr = &a2; // Not ok.
   b.aPtr->data = 10; // OK.    
}
```

The const-ness of `b.aPtr` is analogous to what you would see had you used a raw pointer.

```
int main()
{
   A a1;
   A a2;
   A* const aPtr1 = &a1;
   // This makes aPtr1 a const pointer. That means, you cannot change where it points to
   // but you can still change the value of what it points to.
   aPtr1 = &a2; // Not ok.
   aPtr1->data = 10; // OK.

   A const* aPtr2 = &a1;
   // This makes aPtr2 a pointer to a const object. That means, you can change where it points to
   // but you cannot change the value of what it points to.
   aPtr2 = &a2; // ok.
   aPtr2->data = 10; // Not ok.
}
```

When it comes to references, it is similar but with a small twist. There is no such thing as a non-`const` reference. A reference, once initialized, cannot reference another object.

```
A a1;
A& ref = a1;  // ref cannot be changed to reference any other object.
```

In your case,

```
const PrintString printer;
```

has no effect on the `const`-ness of the member variable `PrintString::os`. It continues to reference a non-`const` `ostream`. This allows you to use:

```
const PrintString printer;
printer("ABC");
```

Answer (score 4):

The *reference* isn't being modified, only what it refers to. This works the same with a pointer. If you had a pointer to `int` data member (`int*`), using it in a `const` member function would make its type `int* const`. You aren't able to change the pointer itself, but you can change what it points to. For example:

```
struct Foo
{
    int a;
    int* p = &a;

    void foo() const
    {
        p = new int; // ERROR! Not allowed to modify const pointer
        *p = 100; // OK, it's a pointer to a non-const int
    }
};
```

So when using `os`, you're only modifying the object that it refers to, not the reference itself.

Answer (score 1):

Try to think of the reference member as a const pointer member variable, and how constness would propagate to member variables when you declare a const object of such class. What gets const is the pointer itself, not what it points to. The same semantics happen with references, The thing is that references are already const (like a const pointer variable), so it doesn't change nothing for them.

```
#include <iostream>

struct S {
    int *p;
    int *const cp;
    int &ref;
};

int main() {
    using namespace std;

    int i = 10;
    const S s{&i, &i, i};

    // s.p = &i; // can't do this, s.p gets const

    *s.p = 20;  // changing the pointee
    cout << i << endl;

    // s.p = &i; // can't do this, s.p was const already, and would get if it weren't

    *s.cp = 30;  // changing the pointee
    cout << i << endl;

    // s.ref ?; // can't make a reference refer to other object

    s.ref = 40;  // changing the pointee
    cout << i << endl;
}
```